# Sessão a partir da Config

Tags: session, cakephp-2

Tenho o seguinte caso: quero enviar um email a partir do cakephp, porém, como há mais de um usuário no banco (cada um contendo um email diferente), preciso enviar o email e senha de cada usuário para o arquivo /app/Config/email.php, ou seja, simplesmente pegar da sessão.
Já há um método que captura os dados do usuário, sendo $this->Session->read('UsuarioLogado'), podendo assim passar o resto dos parâmetros: $this->Session->read('UsuarioLogado')['User']['email'] e $this->Session->read('UsuarioLogado')['User']['senha'], porém ao tentar passar esses valores da sessão para o arquivo email.php, ele dá um erro dizendo que é necessário utilizar isso dentro de uma função.

email.php:

```
public $smtp = array(
            'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
            'port' => 465,
            'from' => array($_SESSION['UsuarioLogado']['User']['email'] => $_SESSION['UsuarioLogado']['User']['nome']),
            'username' => $_SESSION['UsuarioLogado']['User']['email'],
            'password' => $_SESSION['UsuarioLogado']['User']['senha'],
            'transport' => 'Smtp',
            'tls' => false // As of 2.3.0 you can also enable TLS SMTP
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De fato, você não pode definir as propriedades dinamicamente direto no arquivo de configuração de **Email**. Você precisa fazer isto de um `Controller`, por exemplo.

Pelo método [`config()`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/class-CakeEmail.html#_config), você pode tanto passar uma *string* que representa uma das configurações definidas nestes arquivo, ou um *array* com as próprias propriedades de configuração do *SMTP*.

Para isso, faça algo assim:

```
$sess = $this->Session->read('UsuarioLogado');

$Email = new CakeEmail();
$Email->config(array(
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'username' => $sess['User']['email'],
    'password' => $sess['User']['senha'],
));
```

Comment: Faltou apenas o campo 'from', o resto está tudo certo.. Achei estranho não ter algo parecido no manual (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html).. Valeu